# Nicer word for inquisitor

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find a word which means that someone is curious about something. For example, technology inquisitor. Except that inquisitor means that someone is trying to find something in a harsh way and I just want it to mean that they are interested in this.

Comment: A 'Scholar', for example?

Comment: Do you mean they are actually asking about something, or merely interested in a general way? I've added the single-word-request tag: please review the [checklist for this type of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). We need as much information as you can possibly give.

Comment: "researcher" ?  A researcher makes a deliberate effort to dig into a subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Enthusiast** seems like an appropriate word choice.

> [Enthusiast](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enthusiast) (noun): a person who is very interested in and involved with a particular subject or activity.
>   *He is an engineering enthusiast.*

Some synonyms that may also work:

- [Fanatic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fanatic) (In my opinion this is too dramatic, but can definitely be used to describe someone's interest in a certain subject).
- [Aficionado](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aficionado?q=Aficionado) (Ooh. Fancy word!)

Comment: These imply a hobbyist meaning - the original only specifies 'someone is curious about something', like someone who wants to know everything or is even a bit nosey.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working from the adjective "inquisitive". While "inquisitor" may be considered the noun form, it has taken on the harsh implications which you describe.

A more neutral term might be "investigator".

Or, since inquisitive derives from inquire, "inquirer".